# Reproducing a crash from a dump file in Windows Store application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols

I have a dump file of a Metro application created by AdPlus.
I have both the pdb files and the source code.
When I open dmp file in Visual Studio I can see only Disassembled code (asm).
Is there any way to debug source code? How do I add pdbs and debug using source code?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if the file is a dll you just need to put the pdb in the same directory where the dll resides, and in the visual studio debugger you need to point to this file